# STFT in Java without zero-padding

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I've been working on porting code from Python to Java to make a mobile implementation of a Python app. The Python app takes in audio data and extracts features from it through Fourier transformations. It makes use of signal.stft which allows for the [input signal to not be zero-padded](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.stft.html#:%7E:text=nperseg%3D3.-,padded,-bool%2C%20optional) if the user so chooses. To ensure similar results between the python app and the mobile app, I have to be able to create window frames of 800. However, while porting this code to Java, I've been unable to find a library or implement a Fourier transform myself that allows for an arbitrary frame length. The [JDSP library](https://github.com/psambit9791/jdsp/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/psambit9791/jdsp/transform/FastFourier.java#L93) requires that frame lengths above 200 to be zero-padded to the nearest power of two--probably because of it's use of the FastFourierTransform library (when I tried to implement my own STFT with this library, it would crash if my window length was not a power of two). Is there a way to implement STFT in Java that allows for arbitrary frame lengths, like Scipy does? Are there any libraries which already allow this?